# Implement a small Python program to recognize handwitten numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I thought I could implement a very small Python program to recognize handwitten numbers.

## Steps :

1.I write on  a piece of paper, take an image.

2.read it using Python.

3.convert it into grayscale and to 20*20

4.then convert it to 1*400 and added a row at the beginning to make it 1*401

```
img1=Image.open('one.jpg').convert('L')

img1 = img1.resize((20,20))

a=np.reshape(input1,(1,400))

b=np.c_[np.ones(1),a]
```

## What I got:

As part of Andrew ng course on coursera I got weights for hidden layers, so by using a neural network with only one hidden layer I could predict the number by just doing forward propagation.

## The parameters are:

input_layer_size = 20x20 Input Images of Digits,i.e; b 1*401

25 hidden units, theta1 = 25*401 and theta2=10*26

10 labels, from 1 to 10, "0" mapped to label 10

## Python code:

```
//I read the weights to python

weights = scipy.loadmat('ex3weights.mat',squeeze_me = True)
theta1 = weights['Theta1']
theta2 = weights['Theta2']
l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(b,theta1.T))))
c = np.c_[np.ones(1),l1]  //added 1 to make it 1*26
l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(c,theta2.T))))
```

now the (position +1) of the max of l2 will be the output number.

```
#Octave code:
a1=[ones(size(a,1),1),a];
z2=sigmoid(a1*Theta1');
a2=[ones(size(z2,1),1),z2];
a3=sigmoid(a2*Theta2');
[x,p ]= max(a3, [], 2);
p

//here p has the number
```

If all went well I should have got some magic out of this small code,but it worked fine in octave and not in Python. I saved the a in a.mat and loaded it in octave and run the above code and I got the answer. The l2 and the p should be same, right?

I checked every thing, this code is from the http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/
and I even tried his 11 lines of neural network in octave and then I got same output in Python and Octave. This should work right.

Comment: How can I upload a zip file.... Can I edit and resubmit